# How do I add Customer Class field to the SO Screen in Acumatica?

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I am having issues bringing the CustomerClass field in via customization. ACM does not all the value to come through. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Customize Sales Order screen (SO301000) using Acumatica Project Editor.

Use CREATE CONTROLS button from the ADD DATA FIELDS tab to add the control for the field 'Customer__CustomerClassID':

[image]

By default this control is invisible, that might be your issue. You can change that by setting the Visible property to true:
[image]

After publication of the customization, the Customer Class ID field is visible in Sales Order screen:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! How can configure the field so the user is able to edit the field or choose a different value?

Comment: You need to extend the field and merge PXUIFieldAttribute with Enabled=true  to enable it or call PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled method on that field.